# Getting guilds bot is in with invites using discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js, es6-promise

I am trying to make command list servers with invites. What I want is that command outputs array of server invites.
So, the first thing is I cannot `.push()` inside `.then()` block, because the array returns empty and something has to do with callback. I'd try to make use of `Promise`, specifically `Promise.all` with `.map` so the bot can return list of guilds but if I try to make invite to the server, it just outputs `[undefined, undefined]`. Maybe because I didn't specify what to return or I am incorrectly doing it?

Here's the code below:

```js
// headers, client.on and switch statement...
   case "getservers":
      var ServersEmbed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setColor(theme.theme.embedColours[0])
          .setAuthor("Getting server list...")
      ;
      var m = await msg.channel.send(ServersEmbed);
      var l = await Promise.all(client.guilds.cache.map(guild => {
          var inv = guild.channels.cache.filter(i => i.type != "category").random().createInvite();
          return inv.url;
      }));
      console.log(l);
      // m.edit(...
      break;
// more cases and fun...
```

Maybe using `return` inside `Promise.all` block is wrong. Also `client.on("message"...` is async in my source code.

Comment: Try `console.log(inv)`, perhaps it doesn't have a `url` property? JS/async operations don't look bad from the code in the question

Comment: @CertainPerformance well, it becomes reference error telling that `inv` is not defined

Comment: Well, of course you would only be able to log the `inv` at the point that it's defined, inside the callback

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use Promise.all() on the map, if you don't have something to await inside the map function, and you aren't using async on the function, so you can't even use await if you wanted to.

Comment: Async is already used, i have stated in in my question

Answer (score 0):

The OP's issue is that they are assigning the result of Promise.all() but trying to read that variable before the Promise.all() has completed.

When using await, if you want the code to stop continuing on until the Promise actually completes, you must .then() off the promise at some point. Also, I recommend against relying on the cache for things like invites, so instead use the guild Object's .fetchInvites() method and iterate

Here is what I use to obtain all a guild's invites:

```js
// Discord.js v12 API - later versions may use different method/property names.
async function getGuildInvites(guildOBJ) {
  let invites = [];
  await guildOBJ.fetchInvites()
  .then((invite_arr) => {
    invite_arr.forEach((i)=>{
      invites.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(i)));
    });
  });
  return invites;
}

var guild_invites = await getGuildInvites(guild);
```

Just build an array of guild objects like you already are, but instead of trying to map/filter and use the client guild.cache, actively await the fetch, put each object into the array, then you can for loop each array element, calling the getGuildInvites() function, which will wait for each iteration to complete, thus allowing you to either overwrite the guildObject element with it's invites array or you can assign it to an Object that is indexed by the guild.id string. Don't forget that it is unsafe to rely on any Object to stay alive outside of it's promise/fetcher; assigning the resulting Object is ByRef and can be lost, which is why I use JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)) to deep clone...or you can return your own object and properties (which my code actually does as I only want 4 of the invites properties in the first place).

Beware though, the Discord.js docs warn you that the only properties of an invite that are guaranteed to be available are the code, the channel, and the url.

On a side note, I personally see the url property as a convenience to the programmer, since the url is just the string "https://discord.gg/" + invite.code. When I store invite info in a database record, I store the code and not the url, as I can always rebuild the url if I ever needed to.